# tinymce Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

when loading a view that has multple collections and multiple sub views for the main view how do you wait till everything has loaded and render the view with all data. Could someone please leave me some example code on how to do it

backbone:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.data = this.model.toJSON();
    this.collections = [];
    this.collections[0] = new category.CategoriesCollection({ });               
    this.collections[0].fetch();

    this.childViews = [];
    this.childViews[0] = new ImageViewCollection({ collection: new ImageCollection() });                

    //this.model.on('add', this.render(), this);                

    for(var i = 0;  i < this.collections.length; i++) {
        this.listenTo(this.collections[i], 'add', this.render());
    }
},
```

Comment: Listen to a child view event from parent, after rendering trigger event from child view. Count the event and match it with number of child views.

Comment: Your title shows a TinyMCE error, but you're asking about something. Please show a [mcve]. You shouldn't need to wait for each fetch to render a TinyMCE input.